Is identifiability a necessary assumption for the Cramer-Rao bound?
Consider the following setup: a random variable with two outcomes (0,1) with probability mass function parameterized by $x$ as $p(0|x)=\frac{1}{2}+x^2$ and $p(1|x)=\frac{1}{2}-x^2$ with $x\in[0,1/\sqrt{2}]$
It seems to me the regularity assumptions for the Cramer-Rao bound hold:

The Fisher information is well defined (i.e. derivatives of the log-liklihood function exist)
I can swap the order of differentiating with respect to $x$ and the expectation value over the outcomes

But the Fisher information is zero if the unknown parameter is $x=0$. Consequently the Cramer-Rao bound predicts that I cannot learn $x$ with bounded variances. But it seems that I can. This is just an unbiased coin. As I flip it more and more times I should be able to extract $x=0$ with an uncertainty that goes like $1/\sqrt{n}$ where $n$ is the number of flips.
So what silly mistake am I making? What is wrong here?
Edit: see comments below. I think the question now becomes "Is identifiability a necessary assumption for the Cramer-Rao bound?" I think the answer must be no and this would explain the failure of the bound in this example, but I can't find a proof that makes this assumption and I don't see how it follows from the usual regularity conditions.

At least when I learned it, the Cramer-Rao theorem requires that the set of parameters be open, but $[0,1/\sqrt{2}]$ is not.  This is a nice counterexample.  I think the problem is that we can't take the derivatives w.r.t. $x$ at the boundary values $x=0,1/\sqrt{2}$.

Perfect! What if I take the parameter space to be $(-1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2})$?

Can you write down how you compute the fisher information? it doesn't seem that it should be zero.

$I(x) = p(0|x) [d \log p(0|x)/ dx]^2 + p(1|x) [d \log p(1|x)/dx]^2$

Part of the issue here is that I picked $x^2$ as opposed to $x$. In the latter case the fisher information is indeed non-zero. But I don’t see why parameterizing it this way violates anything.

I think that there is no issue. The Cramer-Rao bound says that if $T(Y)$ is an unbiased estimator of $g(x)$, then $\operatorname{Var}(T(Y))\geq \frac{g'(x)^2}{\mathcal{I}(x)}$.  Let $Y\sim\operatorname{Bern}(\frac{1}{2}-x^2)$ as in your question and let $T(Y) = Y$, which is unbiased for $g(x) = \frac{1}{2}-x^2$.  A calculation shows $$\mathcal{I}(x) = \frac{4x^2}{(\frac{1}{2}+x^2)(\frac{1}{2}-x^2)},$$ so as you point out, $\mathcal{I}(0)=0$. However, we also have $g'(x) = 2x$, so $g'(0)=0$ and the Cramer-Rao bound appears to be $\frac{0}{0}$.  We can now take limits to see what happens to the bound:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{g'(x)^2}{\mathcal{I}(x)} = \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{2}+x^2\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}-x^2\right)=\frac{1}{4},
$$
which is exactly what we'd get through the usual parametrization of the Bernoulli family with $p=\frac{1}{2}$.
As another note, I am not sure whether the Cramer-Rao bound holds when $\mathcal{I}(x_0) = 0$.  The proof I learned (which is the same as one of the proofs on Wikipedia) has the following steps (here $S(Y)$ is the score).  First, note that by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(T(Y))\operatorname{Var}(S(Y))}\geq |\operatorname{Cov}(T(Y),S(Y))|$; now, we square both sides and divide by $\operatorname{Var}(S(Y))=\mathcal{I}(x)$ to get the bound.  However, clearly this division part does not work if $\mathcal{I}(x) = 0$.  I am not sure if there is another proof that avoids this issue.
